# Low Quality Contact Photos on "Card" in Android Wear

Tags: android-wear

I own a Moto360. I use Google Hangouts as my default messaging app on my Nexus 5. When the "card" shows up on my smartwatch, the contact image on it is low resolution. It is noticeably blurry.

When someone calls my phone, the photo looks fine. It looks crisp and as high-res as could be. I'm guessing it's the specific apps that cause the low resolution.

Google Hangouts and Instagram both have low quality contact images showing up on my watch.

Is there some kind of solution to this? Am I the only one who has this problem?

Comment: If you don't have a solution can you at least comment if you have the same problem? If I'm the only one I will probably return it. Let me know!

Comment: I notice the same using Hangouts for SMS